# Python double parameters not working

Tags: python

So I have a program and I want to get the tip, using two parameters. I first prompt the user to enter a userBill which is the amount the bill cost and then I promt the user to enter a tip of 15% or 30%, but have them enter it into decimal format. My problem is when I call the method Problem3() it also called the method tip inside of problem3 after getting the values of userBill and tipRate, but I keep getting this error. Sorry for the confusion.

```
>>> def Problem3():
    userBill = input("Enter the total of your bill at the restaurant.")
    tipRate = input("Would you like to tip .15 or .30 of your bill?")
    userBill = int(userBill)
    tipRate = float(tipRate)
    def Tip(userBill, tipRate):
        tipRate1 = .15
        tipRate2 = .30
        userTip = 0

        if tipRate == tipRate1:
            userTip = tipRate1 * userBill
        else:
            userTip = tipRate2 * userBill
        print("Your tip is " + userTip + " since you've want to tip at")
    Tip(userBill, tipRate)

>>> Problem3()
Enter the total of your bill at the restaurant.100
Would you like to tip .15 or .30 of your bill?.15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    Problem3()
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 16, in Problem3
    Tip(userBill, tipRate)
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 15, in Tip
    print("Your tip is " + userTip + " since you've want to tip at")
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
>>>
```

Comment: Ohh i think i know the problem maybe because i didn't called the method yet haha... let me try and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need the conditions and local variables in your `Tip()` function:

```
def Tip(userBill, tipRate):
    userTip = tipRate * userBill
    print("Your tip is {0} since you've want to tip at {1}".format(userTip, tipRate))
Tip(userBill, tipRate)
```

And you really don't even need the internal function:

```
def Problem3():
    userBill = input("Enter the total of your bill at the restaurant.")
    tipRate = input("Would you like to tip .15 or .30 of your bill?")
    userBill = int(userBill)
    tipRate = float(tipRate)
    userTip = tipRate * userBill
    print("Your tip is {0} since you've want to tip at {1}".format(userTip, tipRate))
```